# Azure ML Tabular Dataset : missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream_column'

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk

For the Python API for tabular dataset of AzureML (`azureml.data.TabularDataset`), there are two experimental methods which have been introduced:

1. `download(stream_column, target_path=None, overwrite=False, ignore_not_found=True)`
2. `mount(stream_column, mount_point=None)`

Parameter `stream_column` has been defined as The stream column to mount or download.

What is the actual meaning of `stream_column`? I don't see any example any where?

Any pointer will be helpful.

The stack trace:

```
Method download: This is an experimental method, and may change at any time. Please see https://aka.ms/azuremlexperimental for more information.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_11561/3904436543.py in <module>
----> 1 tab_dataset.download(target_path="../data/tabular")

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/_base_sdk_common/_docstring_wrapper.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
     50     def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
     51         module_logger.warning("Method {0}: {1} {2}".format(func.__name__, _method_msg, _experimental_link_msg))
---> 52         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     53     return wrapped
     54 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/data/_loggerfactory.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    130             with _LoggerFactory.track_activity(logger, func.__name__, activity_type, custom_dimensions) as al:
    131                 try:
--> 132                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    133                 except Exception as e:
    134                     if hasattr(al, 'activity_info') and hasattr(e, 'error_code'):

TypeError: download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream_column'
```

Comment: Looks like AzureML Python SDK has two Tabular Dataset classes exposed over API: azureml.contrib.dataset.TabularDataset and azureml.data.TabularDataset. They have different signatures. No sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update on 5th March, 2022**

I posted this as a support ticket with Azure. Following is the answer I have received:

> As you can see from our documentation of [TabularDataset Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.tabulardataset?view=azure-ml-py),
> the “stream_column” parameter is required. So, that error is occurring
> because you are not passing any parameters when you are calling the
> download method.    The “stream_column” parameter should have the
> stream column to download/mount. So, you need to pass the column name
> that contains the paths from which the data will be streamed.
> Please find an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-labeled-dataset#explore-labeled-datasets-via-pandas-dataframe).